# How to create dummy variables to indicate two values are the same using SAS

Tags: sas, dummy-data

My data looks like:

```
ID      YEAR    A   B
1078    1989    1   0
1078    1999    1   1
1161    1969    0   0
1161    2002    1   1
1230    1995    0   0
1230    2002    0   1
1279    1996    0   0
1279    2003    0   1
1447    1993    1   0
1447    2001    1   1
1487    1967    0   0
1487    2008    1   1
1487    2008    1   0
1487    2009    0   1
1678    1979    1   0
1678    2002    1   1
1690    1989    1   0
1690    1993    0   1
1690    1993    0   0
1690    1996    0   1
1690    1996    0   0
1690    1997    1   1
```

I'd like to create two dummy variables, new and X, the scenarios are as follows:
within each ID-B pair (a pair is 2 observations one with `B=0` and the other `B=1` with `YEAR` closet together in sequence)

1. if the observation with `B=1` has a value of 1 for A then `new=1` for both observations in that pair, otherwise it is 0 for both observations in that pair, and
2. if the pair has the same value in A then `X=0` and if they have different values then `X=1`.

Therefore, the output would be:

```
ID      YEAR    A   B   new X
1078    1989    1   0   1   0
1078    1999    1   1   1   0
1161    1969    0   0   1   1
1161    2002    1   1   1   1
1230    1995    0   0   0   0
1230    2002    0   1   0   0
1279    1996    0   0   0   0
1279    2003    0   1   0   0
1447    1993    1   0   1   1
1447    2001    1   1   1   1
1487    1967    0   0   1   1
1487    2008    1   1   1   1
1487    2008    1   0   0   1
1487    2009    0   1   0   1
1678    1979    1   0   1   0
1678    2002    1   1   1   0
1690    1989    1   0   0   1
1690    1993    0   1   0   1
1690    1993    0   0   0   0
1690    1996    0   1   0   0
1690    1996    0   0   1   1
1690    1997    1   1   1   1
```

My codes are

```
data want;
 set have;
 by ID;
 if B=1 and A=1 then new=1;
 else new=0;
run;

proc sql;
    create table out as
    select a.*,max(a.B=a.A & a.B=1) as new,^(min(A)=max(A)) as X
    from have a
    group by ID;quit;
```

The first one doesn't work and the second one reordered variable B. I am stuck here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very manual solution, I just used the retain statement to identify the pairs (dataset already in the required order).

```
    data start;
        set start;
        retain pair 0;
        if B=0 then pair=pair+1;
    run;

    data ForNew;
        set start(where=(B=1));
        New=(A=B);  /*Boolean variable=1 if the condition in brackets is true*/
        keep pair New;
    run;
/*if A has equal values mean will be 0 or 1*/
    proc means data=start NWAY NOPRINT;
        class pair;
        var A;
        output out=ForX(drop=_: where=(media in (0,1)) keep=pair media) mean(A)=media;
    run;

    data end;
        merge start ForNew ForX(in=INX drop=media);
        by pair;
        X=(^INX);
    run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some research into first./last. processing and the lag function.

The helpful guys here have already gotten you to this point, maybe take this as an opportunity to read the documentation at [SAS' Support Site](http://support.sas.com).

At a high level:

- You need a conditional statement to step through each observation in an ID group
- Find out how many observations are in that group (let's say N obs)
- Flag up if any obs match the logic you mentioned
- Lag back N obs and set your new to 1 or 0 respectively